# Roguelikes tag wiki is weird

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The [roguelikes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roguelikes) [tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/roguelikes/info) is very meta, featuring (old) commentary on what it should contain.  I just rejected a tag edit which tried to add further commentary.  The excerpt is fine, except for the fact that it isn't an excerpt (the main wiki doesn't say any of that).

I know nothing about the genre and don't want to just wipe the wiki.  Could someone more familiar with it clean it up?  Or should we get rid of the tag (see Jason's comment)?

Comment: Is that even a tag we need?  Do we tag StarCraft questions with RTS?

Answer (score 1):

As the stance on genre tags is "We don't use them", we can probably just remove the tag.

You'll need a tag for [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146/whats-the-key-to-failure-in-roguelikes) and [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5195/what-attributes-makes-a-game-a-roguelike) since those two are the only ones about the actual genre. Once you get past that step, we can just de-tag the 5 other instances and be on our merry way.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what tag would be applicable to general questions about a genre besides the genre tag.  Possibly `[terminology]` for the one ... I'd say close both, I think they're bad questions, but I don't think that will happen.

Comment: Could you state why you feel they are bad questions? It'd help aid in their closure if you did that.

Comment: The "attributes" question is a very wide and open discussion - I think it falls under the "entire book" clause; there are definitely entire wikis / podcasts / blogs trying to answer that question. The "key to failure" is also too general. For example in the accepted answer 1, 3, 4, and 5 don't apply to Zaga-33; 3 doesn't apply to Brogue; 1 doesn't apply to bands, generally; I would actually give the opposite advice in ADOM for 4, a strong focus in that game is often key to survival. All five points are more "advice for hacks" than "advice for roguelikes".

Comment: How would you tag questions about a minor roguelike that hardly anyone has heard of? Using obscure names as tags has the problem that they aren't linked to other related games, so people who are interested in roguelikes in general won't find these questions (we have the same problem on [scifi.se], but there subgenres are very subjective, at least [tag:roguelike] is relatively well-defined).

Comment: @Gilles This is the same case for any genre at all. STG, FPS, RPG, roguelike, action... there's always obscure games no one has heard of, that fans of that genre would like to be able to easily find. Or even easily navigate among those that *aren't* obscure. Applying it to only some games of a genre is confusing to end users, and only some games from some genres would be even more confusing. We need a solution for that, but genre tags have (actually demonstrably, in our history) failed to accomplish that goal, so some entirely different meta data about each game tag would be necessary.